# How do I turn on GOD mode in the first Commander Keen?

Tags: commander-keen

I'm playing through the first Commander Keen and sick of falling on clam shells. How do I turn on GOD mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Press <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, all at the same time. I believe you can do this at any point in the game. There should be a notification that pops up when you've done this successfully.

You can also press <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, all at the same time, to get the pogo stick, full ammo, and all key cards. You will still be vulnerable to enemies in this mode.