# How do I enter the cheat codes for Noclip, Immortality, etc?

Tags: commander-keen

In the original Commander Keen series, there were keyboard-entered cheat codes that granted, among other things, immortality, noclip, and flight.  I think those were the three major ones, and I would like to activate them in my Steam version of Commander Keen for...research purposes.

Do these cheat codes work the same as in the original?  Do they work at all?

Comment: May or may not be what you are looking for. I see mixed reports on whether this works. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=114956131.

Comment: have you already tried this? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26820/how-do-i-turn-on-god-mode-in-the-first-commander-keen?rq=1

Comment: @Colin D Not yet, though actually I think I'm thinking of the later Keen games that had Noclip.

Comment: I figured you weren't directly interested in GOD mode, but if the old input methods still work for some of the keen games, then it might work for the later ones as well.

Comment: I have tried it. It works in the first 3 episodes of Commander Keen, but no luck in the later two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two linked articles in the comments combined show how to enable cheats in Commander Keen - The Steam Tutorial shows how to enable those cheats in 4 - 6, and the question linked "How do I turn on GOD mode in the first Commander Keen" explains how to turn on cheats for games 1 - 3.

However, the definitive answer can be found [here](http://www.commander-keen.com/game-cheats.php), for all versions and all methods necessary for turning cheats on in all the classic Commander Keen games.

Note that on Steam specifically, for the later episodes, you must first input <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, holding down all at once, or the cheats won't work.

Direct from that article, here's how to activate cheats.

---

**Cheats for Episodes 1-3**

*The key combinations need to be pressed at the same time.*

- <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> - Gives pogostick, all keycards, and full ammo.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - Pass through an unplayed level on world map.
- <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - Will put your keen in GOD Mode and will give you a jump cheat.

**Cheats for Episodes 4-6**

*The key combinations need to be pressed at the same time.
Some versions might require pressing <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> before using cheats.*

- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> - God mode
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> - Free items
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> - Jump cheat
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> - No clipping
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> - View hidden areas in the level.
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - Set border color (1-15)
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Show number of active/inactive objects in the level
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - Record a demo
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - End the current level
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> - Display memory usage
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - Slow motion
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> - Sprite test
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - Warp to any level
- <kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> - Reveal hidden areas